# DL4J: Wrong input size - expected matrix

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j

I’m trying to get my network to evaluate an INDArray. This is my network:
public class DQN {

```
private final int inputSize;
private final int outputSize;
private final MultiLayerNetwork network;


public DQN(int inputSize, int outputSize){

    this.inputSize = inputSize;
    this.outputSize = outputSize;

    MultiLayerConfiguration config = setConfig();
    this.network = new MultiLayerNetwork(config);
    this.network.init();
}

private MultiLayerConfiguration setConfig(){
    return new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(12345)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .updater(new AdaGrad(0.5))
            .activation(Activation.RELU)
            .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT)
            .l2(0.0001)
            .list()
            .layer(0, new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn(this.inputSize).nOut(250).weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER).activation(Activation.RELU) //First hidden layer
                    .build())
            .layer(1, new OutputLayer.Builder().nIn(250).nOut(this.outputSize).weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER).activation(Activation.SOFTMAX) //Output layer
                    .lossFunction(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
                    .build())
            .build();
}

public INDArray evaluate(INDArray vec){
    return this.network.output(vec);
}
```

}

Unfortunately, whenever I try to call evaluate with my INDArray, I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" org.deeplearning4j.exception.DL4JInvalidInputException: Input that is not a matrix; expected matrix (rank 2), got rank 1 array with shape [23]. Missing preprocessor or wrong input type? (layer name: layer0, layer index: 0, layer type: DenseLayer)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.BaseLayer.preOutputWithPreNorm(BaseLayer.java:308)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.BaseLayer.preOutput(BaseLayer.java:291)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.BaseLayer.activate(BaseLayer.java:339)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.layers.AbstractLayer.activate(AbstractLayer.java:258)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.outputOfLayerDetached(MultiLayerNetwork.java:1303)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.output(MultiLayerNetwork.java:2415)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.output(MultiLayerNetwork.java:2378)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.output(MultiLayerNetwork.java:2369)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.output(MultiLayerNetwork.java:2356)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork.output(MultiLayerNetwork.java:2452)
    at wmaclean.rl.dqn.DQN.evaluate(DQN.java:51)
```

My inputs are rank-1 vectors with 23 elements, but the net seems to be wanting a matrix. Does anyone know why? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my issue. For anyone having similar issues, make sure you specify the shape when creating the INDArray:

```
Nd4j.create(data, **new int[]{1, vectorSizeCount}**)
```